# Unity Instantiate GameObject not working in iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have a level loading script that draws a level from an array representation loaded from file. This works fine in unity editor but when I build for ios those objects dynamically drawn do not display.

Here is the code that does the drawing:

```
void DrawNewLevel(int level) {
    LevelEditor.Level lvl = new LevelEditor.Level (1, level);
    for (int x = 0; x < 260; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 23; y++) {
            GameObject gameObject;
            if (lvl.LevelContents[x, y].BlockType != LevelEditor.BlockType.Empty) {
                Debug.Log("drawing non-null");
                if (lvl.LevelContents[x, y].BlockType == LevelEditor.BlockType.Floor) {
                    gameObject = Instantiate(Floor);
                    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(x, 23-y, 0);
                } else if (lvl.LevelContents[x, y].BlockType == LevelEditor.BlockType.FloorBad) {
                    gameObject = Instantiate(FloorBad);
                    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(x, 23-y, 0);
                } else if (lvl.LevelContents[x, y].BlockType == LevelEditor.BlockType.SmartRocketLauncher) {
                    gameObject = Instantiate(SmartRocketLauncher);
                    gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(x, 23-y, 1);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Linked code looks fine, are you sure that the level data is loading correctly?

Comment: hmm you know thats a good point. is the path different in iOS? I will look into this.

Comment: Well, I'm making an app at the moment, and if my data is in the persistent data folder on the device, then I have to go: `"file://"+Application.persistentdatapath+"/video.mp4"` etc. Where exactly is your level data being stored?